# How to set title for Android.Support.V7.App ActionBar (AppCompatActivity) using Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, appcompatactivity

I am trying to set the tile of the Android.Support.V7.App ActionBar under AppCompatActivity using the following code for Xamarin.Android. It is not working for me.

SupportActionBar.Title = "";

Can anyone please guide me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code that does the job.  I initialize the title in the OnCreateOptionsMenu method, not in the OnCreate method.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(LayoutResource);

        Toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        if (Toolbar != null)
        {
            SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
            Toolbar.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(MenuId, menu);
        Toolbar.Title = "my title";

        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```